# How to make boxplot more readable and scale numbers?

Tags: python

I am trying to plot boxplot, however, I don't know how to change the numbers appearance and view of the plot. Here is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
sns.boxplot(x='is_customer', y='revenue',data=accounts.dropna())
plt.autoscale()
```

And as the result I get:

[image: boxplot]

Y-axis, have huge range of numbers: from 0 until 100000000+.
How can I make it more readable, also numbers are in scientific type 'e notation', I need to turn them to normal numeric variant.

Comment: Have you tried converting y data to log scale? [Here are the numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html).

Comment: yes, but it doesn't give anything

Comment: “Doesn’t give anything”; please clarify.  We use this technique a lot when the data has a *very* wide distribution, such as yours.  The technique itself certainly works.

Comment: You are creating an axe then you don't use it. Bind it to 
 seaboard call using ax switch, then update scale using axe not plt

Comment: I have managed how to use np.log10, thank you. However, my plots right now show me log numbers, is it possible to return original values?